# How to DRY up repetitive Ruby code?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, coding-style, dry, code-cleanup

I'm relatively new to ruby. Can this be DRYed up? And how?

```
def primary_phone
  number_to_phone self.primary_phone_number
end

def primary_phone=(number)
  self.primary_phone_number = number.gsub(/\D/, '')
end

def secondary_phone
  number_to_phone self.secondary_phone_number
end

def secondary_phone=(number)
  self.secondary_phone_number = number.gsub(/\D/, '')
end

def fax
  number_to_phone self.fax_phone_number
end

def fax=(number)
  self.fax_phone_number = number.gsub(/\D/, '')
end
```

I'm using this code in Rails as a kind of buffer between the database, which is storing the numbers as integers, and the user form which is inputing them as strings.

Comment: Looks like you need to define a custom data type. I've not done that in ActiveRecord, which I assume you are using for your data models?

Comment: Yes, I'm using ActiveRecord. How do you create custom data types? Know of any good links or am I hunting for some documentation somewhere?

Comment: I googled it, and I'm not sure custom data types are what I'm looking for. It seems like overkill. I just want to get and set integers with a special format, one that's already halfway supported by rails.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All you need is,

```
before_save :sanitize_phone_number_fields

def sanitize_phone_number_fields
  [:primary_phone, :secondary_phone, :fax].each{|attr| self.send(attr).gsub!(/\D/, '')}
end
```

Comment: Use `.each` here, not `.map`.  You're just iterating, not attempting to create a new version of the array.